# (iOS) BLE Scanning in background and screen locked

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm wondering if there is any workaround that would allow the iOS device to scan via Bluetooth even when the screen is locked. Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I have been able to successfully scan and advertise on the iPhone when the app is in the foreground or background. However, I'm facing an issue where the scanning stops as soon as the screen is locked.

PS. I am not going to connect with any other devices but just want to scan and get the beacon of neighbor devices.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS BLE background scanning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269375/ios-ble-background-scanning)

Comment: No, I don't think so. Mine works well in the background and screen on, but the issue is related to whenever the screen is locked.